# intellij on mac: can I have standard mac copy/paste keyboard shortcuts and also emacs?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij idea 11.1.2. I am on a mac, I have emacs as my general keyboard scheme, and I'm frequently tripped up when I hit apply-c or apple-v and expect them to work. Anybody got a recipe to enable them without undoing the emacs bindings?

Comment: Did you try to modify your Emacs keymap in `Preferences` | `Keymap`?

Comment: I want *both* sets. Currently, the edit menu shows some strange IJ-specific things, and then the emacs bindings also work. I'm off to look at the prefs some more.

Comment: Ah, I can add. Make an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Preferences` | `Keymap` it's possible to add multiple keyboard shortcuts to a single action.